# Parent Ordered by number of child tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parent

I have a tbl_user , which contains information about user, and I have a tbl_article, which contains articles + the ID of the tbl_user

We have a parent-child relation, because every user may have many articles, that's why I included user_id in the articles table.

I'd like to list the 10 users that have most articles... I've searched everywhere though I couldn't find it...I've thought about it , but in vain, I'm not good in SQL Queries.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What if there is a tie for 10th place?

Comment: I'm just using mySQL with PHP... it's about a web project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP(10)
  tbl_user.id,
  COUNT(tbl_article.user_id)
FROM
  tbl_user
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_article
    ON tbl_user.id = tbl_article.user_id
GROUP BY
  tbl_user.id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(tbl_article.user_id) DESC
LIMIT
  10
```

Depending on which RDBMS you use, you may need `TOP(10)` or `LIMIT 10`, etc.  I included both so you can see, but only use the one that is used by your RDBMS ;)

Comment: Thank you friend ... +1, I've already get it working, if only there's an option to choose two best answers ;)

Comment: @SimoTAQI - Awwwwww, I had the `LIMIT` version first ;)  You got what you needed though, that's what counts.  Not my sense of vanity.  Or need for external praise and justification.  My existance isn't dependant on votes and points in StackOverflow.  ***cry***

Comment: hhhhh, Then I'll check the first conversation between you two :-)
Good, Best Answer :-)

Comment: Good move accepting this one :)  He did indeed have it first.

Comment: @Dems does a points dance and rolls of the floor in laughter.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 10
    UserID, COUNT(Article)
FROM tbl_User u
INNER JOIN tbl_Article a
    ON a.Userid = u.userid
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY COUNT(article) DESC
```

All you need is a `GROUP BY` and a `JOIN`.

If there is a potential for users with 0 articles that you want to include, you should use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Optionally you can also `COUNT(DISTINCT Article)` if there is a concern about duplicates.

Comment: If one of the top 10 has 0 articles, this won't include it ;)

Comment: If  they have 0 articles then they shouldn't be included, I'm guessing, since there would be an infinite-way tie with all other users with no articles.

Comment: I feel sad, I never thought JNK would guess ;(  [+1 anyway, since being anal like me isn't *always* a help :)]

Comment: @Dems - LOL sorry to burst your bubble!  I'll add a note for  you.

Comment: I got an error trying this : 

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10 id_user, COUNT(id_article) FROM tbl_users u INNER JOIN tbl_article a ON a.id' at line 1

Comment: @SimoTAQI - OK so for MySQL you need to use `LIMIT 10` at the end instead of `TOP 10` at the beginning of the query.  The `TOP 10` is for SQL Server.